# Angular 8 with Jest - 'jasmine' has no exported member 'SpyObj'

Tags: angular, jasmine, jestjs, angular-cli, angular-jest

I have an Angular CLI project that has the default Karma test runner.
I used [this tutorial](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-cli-ng-test-with-jest-in-3-minutes-v2-1060ddd7908d) to replace Karma with Jest and notice some tests are passing some failing.

For example, declaring a variable on test level:

```
let mockObj: jasmine.SpyObj<MyClass>;
```

throws the error:

```
error `"Namespace 'jasmine' has no exported member 'SpyObj'`
```

```
@angular-builders/jest: "^8.3.2"
jest: "^24.9.0"
jasmine-core: "3.5.0"
@types/jest: "^24.9.0"
@types/jasmine: "3.5.0"
@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Jest spies and mocks instead of Jasmine spies when you choose Jest. Or some other test double library like [Sinon](https://sinonjs.org/).

Jest [class mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks) example

```js
import SoundPlayer from './sound-player';

const mockPlaySoundFile = jest.fn();
jest.mock('./sound-player', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {playSoundFile: mockPlaySoundFile};
  });
});

beforeEach(() => {
  SoundPlayer.mockClear();
  mockPlaySoundFile.mockClear();
});

it('The consumer should be able to call new() on SoundPlayer', () => {
  const soundPlayerConsumer = new SoundPlayerConsumer();
  // Ensure constructor created the object:
  expect(soundPlayerConsumer).toBeTruthy();
});

it('We can check if the consumer called the class constructor', () => {
  const soundPlayerConsumer = new SoundPlayerConsumer();
  expect(SoundPlayer).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});

it('We can check if the consumer called a method on the class instance', () => {
  const soundPlayerConsumer = new SoundPlayerConsumer();
  const coolSoundFileName = 'song.mp3';
  soundPlayerConsumer.playSomethingCool();
  expect(mockPlaySoundFile.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual(coolSoundFileName);
});
```